# SQL Averaging max values with nested Order By

Tags: mysql

I have student testing records in a SQL database where individual students could have multiple scores. I would like to find the highest score (max) for each student and them summarize that data by grade level (order by). I tried nesting "order by" but it did not work. And when I do a max(avg(score)) I get an error.

### Example Record:

```
studentID    gradeLevel    score  
student_1    10            495  
student_1    10            365
student_2     9            652
student_2     9            589
student_3    10            612
student_3    10            485
student_4     9            358
student_4     9            600
```

### Desired results:

```
Grade_9  626  (652+600)/2
Grade_10 554  (495+612)/2
```

Any help and/or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using a subquery:

```
select gradelevel, avg(maxscore)
from (
  select studentid, gradelevel, max(score) maxscore
  from yourtable
  group by studentid, gradelevel
  ) t
group by gradelevel
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62399/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  distinct level,max(max_score),avg(max_score) 
from
(
select student_id as 'id',grad_level as 'level',max(score) as 'mx_score'
from scor_table_name
group by sutedent_id,grad_level
) RS
group by level;
```